# How to write 2 different values in one cell in Excel with UFT

Tags: excel, hp-uft

How can I write 2 different values ​​in one cell in excel with UFT? 
for example: 
at the first time I want to write "x" to the cell 
at the second time I want to write "y" next to the "X" that I wrote earlier

Comment: How do you add "x" to the cell? So use the same approach to add "xy"

Comment: If I first write X and later i write Y, then only Y remains  in the cell, I want the cell to appear XY

Comment: So copy the cell, add the new input

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to edit the cell without copying it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the value of the cell with what you want

example:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

objWorkbook.SaveAs("c:\test.xlsx")

objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = "x"

' Below will append append the value you add after ampersand (&) to the cell value

objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value & "y"

objExcel.Quit

Set objWorkbook = nothing
Set objExcel = nothing
```